# how to calculate child property based on parent property in sass

Tags: css, sass

here is the simple html sample:

```
<div class='parent'>
    parent div
    <div class='myDiv'>
        child div
    </div>

</div>
```

I want change child div style based on parent property style. I do not want to use @media for child. But e.g. once parent changes its background color to something specific then I want change child background color, e.g. change child background only if parent changed to RED. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but neither with CSS or Sass, since Sass is based on CSS and the latter does not support conditional statements (yet). You will have to use Javascript instead.

You can however apply a certain styling to a descendent if a certain selector matches the parent.

```
// HTML

<div class="red">
  Parent
  <div>
    Child
  </div>
</div>


// SCSS

.red {
  background-color: red;
  
  > div {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/LudwigGeorgImmanuel/pen/abmPJmZ